# SQLAlchemy hybrid property values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following:

```
 @hybrid_property
    def edate(self) -> Date:
        return func.ADDDATE(self.adate, text(f'INTERVAL {self.elife} month'))
```

As part of an Items base class. `adate` is a Date column and `elife` is an Integer column.

When I query for `edate` it tries to access the class in stead of the value.

```
"Unknown column 'Items.elife' in 'field list'"
```

How can I change this to access the value?

Comment: I changed `self.elife` to `self.elife.expression` and now it works.